# Sort a gtk.TreeColumn by date value

Tags: python, sorting, gtk, pygtk, gtktreeview

I have a `gtk.ListStore` attached to a `gtk.Treeview`

The first column of this `gtk.ListStore` is of `str` type and contains a date value (dd/mm HH:MM:SS)

I want to sort the first `gtk.TreeviewColumn` by date so, I have wrote :

```
listStore = gtk.ListStore(str, str, str, str, str, str, str, str)
treeview = gtk.TreeView()
treeview.set_model(listStore)

cell = gtk.CellRendererText()
column = gtk.TreeViewColumn('Date', cell, text=0)
column.set_sort_column_id(0)
treeview.append_column(column)
```

But the sorting doesn't works fine : It sort by day, not by date.

How can I do to make the sorting by date ?

Thanks

EDIT :

To make the sorting easier, the month value is stored as number (From 01 to 12).

Comment: Your edit sounds like you'd rather display months names. Everything becomes easier if you store datetime instances instead of strings.

Comment: Not really. I do not have preference. The date provide from syslog file, so the month is at `Mmm` format which is the month abbreviated in english, on 3 chars (Jan, Feb ...). Storing the month values as int should allow me to more easily sort but also has the advantage of being universal (not locale dependant).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution by using the `Gtk.TreeSortable.set_sort_func()` :

```
listStore = gtk.ListStore(str, str, str, str, str, str, str, str)
listStore.set_sort_func(0, date_compare, None)
treeview = gtk.TreeView()
treeview.set_model(listStore)

cell = gtk.CellRendererText()
column = gtk.TreeViewColumn('Date', cell, text=0)
column.set_sort_column_id(0)
treeview.append_column(column)
...
```

And I have wrote my `date_compare` function :

(Maybe it have a most elegant manner to wrote this `date_compare` function : I would be happy to hear yours :-))

```
def date_compare(model, row1, row2, user_data):
    # Returns : 
    # - a negative integer if iter1 sorts before iter2,
    # - zero if they are equal,
    # - a positive integer if iter2 sorts before iter1.

    sort_column, _ = model.get_sort_column_id()
    date1 = model.get_value(row1, sort_column)
    date2 = model.get_value(row2, sort_column)

    # We split the date string to an array : 
    #  0  |   1   |   2  |    3    |    4
    # day | month | hour | minutes | seconds
    values1 = re.split("[ /:]", date1)
    values2 = re.split("[ /:]", date2)

    if values1[1] < values2[1] :
        return -1
    elif values1[1] == values2[1] : # same month => we compare by day
        if values1[0] < values2[0] :
            return -1
        elif values1[0] == values2[0] : # same month and day => we compare by hour
            if values1[2] < values2[2] :
                return -1
            elif values1[2] == values2[2] : # same month, day and hour => we compare by minute
                if values1[3] < values2[3] :
                    return -1
                elif values1[3] == values2[3] : # same month, day, hour and minute => we compare by second
                    if values1[4] < values2[4] :
                        return -1
                    elif values1[4] == values2[4] : # same month, day, hour, minute and second => it's same date !
                        return 0
                    else :
                        return 1
                else :
                    return 1
            else :
                return 1
        else :
            return 1
    else :
        return 1
```

Comment: The built-in cmp function works for sequences and returns negative or positive values: values1[0], values1[1] = values1[1], values1[0] # month before day; return cmp(values1, values2)

Comment: I don't know how to use this. Can you explain or post a snippet ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

is better change dates to english format with leading 0 in month/day and compare strings with >

Comment: Overkill perhaps?

Comment: maybe try: date = re.sub('(\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d\d\d)', r"\3-\1-\2", date)